# For loops in my mastermind game

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop in my game to make it so when the number of guess's gets added up it goes into the for loop and gives the number of correct guess's. This is for my computer science class and we have to incorperate the for loop into the program.

```
if (guess1 == Secret_code[0]) {
    System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
}

if (guess2 == Secret_code[1]) {
    System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
}

if (guess3 == Secret_code[2]) {
    System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
}

if (guess4 == Secret_code[3]) {
    System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
}

do {
    System.out.println("What is the number one peg in my code???");
    guess1 = Guess.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the number two peg in my code???");
    guess2 = Guess.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the number three peg in my code???");
    guess3 = Guess.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the number four peg in my code???");
    guess4 = Guess.nextInt();
    if (guess1 == Secret_code[0]) {
        System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
    }
    if (guess2 == Secret_code[1]) {
        System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
    }
    if (guess3 == Secret_code[2]) {
        System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
    }
    if (guess4 == Secret_code[3]) {
        System.out.println(" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
    }
}
while ((guess1 != Secret_code[0]) & (guess2 != Secret_code[1]) & (guess3 != Secret_code[2]) & (guess4 != Secret_code[3]));    

public static void CorrectGuess(int[] Secret_code) {
    //Variables
    int Correctspot;

    for (Secret_code[0] = 0; Secret_code[0] < 3; Secret_code[0]++)
        Correctspot = +1;
}
```

Comment: no problem.... just need to add in for loops that can calculate the number of correct guesses

Comment: This site is not for code requests. You come here when you have a problem implementing something yourself, usually showing your attempt or any research done on the subject. If you do not understand the situation, please talk to your teacher about it, as they are the ones who get paid to make sure you know this stuff, and can't properly teach you if they don't know if there's something you don't understand

Comment: i do have a problem implementing a for loop..... nice

Comment: So, what's the problem then? If it's "I don't know how to", then you should let your teacher know. Not to mention, there are tons of tutorials online, such as [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). But as I said, this is something your teacher should know, so he can show you the same way he showed the class; don't wanna fall behind.

Comment: Mind that `Correctspot = + 1;` doesn't increase the value of `Correctspot`, it just sets the value to `1`, on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you just a sample because like they said its not our job, but I feel bad because their are some bad teachers out of there. I would also build an array because this will solve all the problems you may come across

```
//make a Scanner obj
Int[] guessArray = {10, 20, 30, 5};    
int useranswer = 0;
int loopCount = 0;

while(loopCount < 4) {
    System.out.println("blalalala for Guess #" + (loopCount+1));
    useranswer = input.nextInt();

    if(useranswer == guessArray[loopCount]) {
        loopCount++;
    }//end of if

}//end of while loop
```

Having an **array list** will help keep everything in order and you are able to resign the values after this loop later in the program. You always need to be careful with `while` loops because if code wrong, you could end up crashing the computer.

I would also look up `for` loops because depending on your future problems either `for` or `while` could work the best.

**TO whom edited coding style[1]:** NOTE: I code by spacing everything out because it helps me see everything, if this is a problem please let me know. So I will be able to change it afterwords